# Database Design Input

Tags: database-design

After gathering info bit here and there and looking at [this URL](http://www.accountingsoftware411.com/Press/Insider/InsiderArticleView.aspx?docid=10330&iid=1025):

Here is the proposed design

```
1. ChartAccounts

ChartAccountID INT
TenantID INT
ChartAccountCode VARCHAR(256)
Dimension1Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension2Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension3Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension4Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension5Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension6Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension7Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension8Code VARCHAR(16)
IsExpired BIT
ExpiredDate DATETIME
```

Note: I can see that the Dimension/Segment is limited to only 8 BUT I don't think any other company will have more than 8. I am open to suggestion with this approach.
We put TenantID because in this application we store for multiple clients/organisation.

Sample Data:

```
1|310-01-4000|310|01|4000||||||
2|310-02-4000|310|02|4000||||||
3|310-03-4000|310|03|4000||||||
4|320-01-4000|320|01|4000||||||
5|320-02-4000|320|02|4000||||||
6|320-03-4000|320|03|4000||||||
7|200-01-5000|200|01|5000||||||
```

...

```
2. Dimensions

DimensionID INT
ParentDimensionID INT
TenantID INT
DimensionTypeID INT
DimensionCode VARCHAR(16)
DimensionName VARCHAR(128)
DimensionDescription VARCHAR(256)
```

Sample Data:

```
1|0|1|1|100|CORPORATE CONSOLIDATION|
2|1|1|1|300|MARKETING|
3|2|1|1|310|USA MARKETING|
4|2|1|1|320|EUROPE MARKETING|
5|2|1|1|330|CANADA MARKETING|
6|1|1|1|200|PRODUCTION|
7|1|1|1|900|CORPORATE OVERHEAD|
8|0|1|2|00|ALL LINES|
9|8|1|2|01|LINE 1|
10|8|1|2|02|LINE 2|
11|8|1|2|03|LINE 3|
12|0|1|3|4000|Expense on phone
13|0|1|3|5000|Expense on DATA

3. DimensionTypes

DimensionTypeID INT
TenantID INT
DimensionTypeCode VARCHAR(32)
DimensionTypeName VARCHAR(128)
DimensionTypeDescription VARCHAR(512)
ChartAccountSequence INT
Length INT
```

Sample Data:

```
1|1|DEPARTMENT|Department| |1|5
2|1|LINE|Line| |2|5
3|1|NATURALACCOUNT|Natural Account| |3|5

4. TRANSACTION

TransID INT
TransDate DATETIME
PhoneNo VARCHAR(32)
CostDescription VARCHAR(128)
Amount MONEY
ChartAccountID INT
```

Sample Data:

```
1|2009-05-01 17:00AM|0290000000|Local Call|30.00|1
2|2009-05-01 18:01AM|0390000000|Local Call|25.50|2
```

...

Any thoughts about this? Especially for the ChartAccount table? As you can see it sets to 8 (Dimension8Code) which is that is the downside of this. But I don't think any company will have that many dimensions?

Within the dimension table itself it has DimensionID/ParentDimensionID relationship to cater the structure within the dimension itself. Or do you have a better idea?

I appreciate your comments. Again this is not an accounting system .. it's just a simple allocation cost using the chart of account.

Comment: The TenantID column in the ChartAccounts table seems to be misplaced; the data doesn't look much like integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: I can see that the Dimension/Segment is limted to only 8 BUT I don't think other company will have more than 8. I am open suggestion with this approach.

Smells bad. Make a one-to-many relation to a table of dimension_segments.

Or maybe it's a many-to-many between chartAccounts and dimensions, since I don't know what a "dimension" is.

Better yet, why not explain what you're trying to model; it's hard to advise you on whether the model works, without knowing what it's supposed to be a model *of*.

Comment: Hi tpdi

If you looked the sample data in the post, the dimension is actually the component of the ChartOfAccount (commonly used by Finance/Accountng system). Let say:

ChartOfAccount is 310-01-4000 what it means is actually:

This COA consist:
310: Division of USA Marketing
01: Line of Line 1
7000: Natural Account of "Expense of phone"

You can attached this COA (ChartOfccount) into any cost/income within your individual transaction.

Hope this help. 

I now it smells bad :) by setting the limit of 8 in this case. But I don't if there is another choice.

Comment: Somebody who knows both multidimensional modeling and COA is going to have to straighten this out.  That's not me.  I understand "dimension" as used in DW or star schema, but I don't understand COA as used in accounting.  It looks like the COA number is a composite key concatenated into a single data element.  Sort of like VIN.

Answer (score 1):

anytime you see fields like this:
Dimension1Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension2Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension3Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension4Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension5Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension6Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension7Code VARCHAR(16)
Dimension8Code VARCHAR(16)

You need a related table instead. Trust me this will be anightmare to query and maintain.